# How to Check that FragmentTransaction.replace() Updates Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction, fragmentmanager

I am a little confused as to how you would check that FragmentTransaction replaces a Fragment. What I mean by this is that you make a reference to a `Layout` in your XML file when you call this method. The method does not actually replace the `Layout` with a `Fragment`, but replaces whats inside said `Layout` with the `Fragment` you want. Because of this, you cannot check to see if it is updated by referencing the Layout. In addition to this, you cannot define a `Fragment` inside the XML and reference it as it will be casted as a `View` and not a `Fragment`. How would you go about testing this method's execution? Thank You!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The question is a bit unclear to me, so I'll answer to the best of my abilities. If you're just asking how you can check if a certain line in a method has been executed, you can log it using https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html.

If you're looking to see if a certain fragment (let's say with a layout file called `fragment1.xml`) has been successfully placed in your layout, you can check using:

`Fragment myFragment = getSupportFragmentManager.findFragmentByID(R.id.fragment1);
if (myFragment != null) 
     // has not been put in your layout successfully.`

Comment: Fragment transaction (if you do not not use `commitNow()` transaction) is performed after some time of your `commit()` and you can get `myFragment == null` right after `commit()`.